# Next Page, for data editing

Tags: coldfusion

I did SEARCHing code, something like this.

```
--pageone.cfm--

<cfparam name="Form.studNo" default="" />

<form action="pagetwo.cfm" method="POST">
<label> Please insert ID:
<input name="studNo" value="<cfoutput>#Form.studNo#</cfoutput>" />
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

--pagetwo--

SELECT * FROM students
WHERE students_ID IN (#Form.studNo#)
```

On page two, I will display the details of student's info and user can edit a new information if the data is not right.

I'm thinking of, displaying data of one student per page and user can click Next for the next students (ID that has been inserted) on pageone.cfm

Can anyone help me with these?

@henry.
I did try something like this.

--example.cfm--

```
<CFPARAM NAME="StartRow" DEFAULT="1">
<CFPARAM NAME="DisplayRows" DEFAULT="1">

<CFQUERY NAME="getStudent" DATASOURCE="#dsn#" 
         CACHEDWITHIN="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,15,0)#">
         SELECT *
         FROM students
</CFQUERY>


<CFSET ToRow = StartRow + (DisplayRows - 1)>
<CFIF ToRow GT getStudent.RecordCount>
    <CFSET ToRow = getStudent.RecordCount>
</CFIF>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Next/Previous Record Browsing</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>


<CFOUTPUT>
<H4>Displaying records #StartRow# - #ToRow# from the 
#getStudent.RecordCount# data inserted.</H4>
</CFOUTPUT>

<!--- create the header for the table --->
<TABLE CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0">
<TR BGCOLOR="#888888">
  <TH>Name</TH>
  <TH>ID</TH>
  <TH>Gender</TH>
  <TH>E-mail</TH>
</TR>    

<CFOUTPUT QUERY="getStudent" STARTROW="#StartRow#"
          MAXROWS="#DisplayRows#">
<TR BGCOLOR="##C0C0C0">
  <TD>#Name#</TD>
  <TD>#ID#</TD>
  <TD>#Gender#</TD>
  <TD>#Email#</TD>
</TR>    
</CFOUTPUT>
</TABLE>

<CFSET Next = StartRow + DisplayRows>
<CFSET Previous = StartRow - DisplayRows>

<!--- Create a previous records link if the records being displayed aren't the
      first set --->
<CFOUTPUT>
<CFIF Previous GTE 1>
   <A HREF="example.cfm?StartRow=#Previous#"><B>Previous #DisplayRows# 
      Records</B></A>
<CFELSE>
Previous Records  
</CFIF>

<CFIF Next LTE getStudent.RecordCount>
    <A HREF="example.cfm?StartRow=#Next#"><B>Next 
    <CFIF (getStudent.RecordCount - Next) LT DisplayRows>
      #Evaluate((getStudent.RecordCount - Next)+1)#
    <CFELSE>
      #DisplayRows#
    </CFIF>  Records</B></A>
<CFELSE>
Next Records   
</CFIF>
</CFOUTPUT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please do not overwrite questions after you have received an answer(s), because the responses you received will no longer make sense. If you are new to this site, Stack Overflow is not a forum. It is a Q&A site, so things work a bit differently than you might expect. For a brief overview of how it works, take the [Quick Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also, if your questions are consistently receiving down votes, it is usually an indication the questions are too broad, unclear or demonstrate a lack of effort, you may want to review [Ask] for tips on improving them.

Answer (score 0):

You may use session to store the specified IDs in pageone.cfm, then go through the array of IDs and use array index as the current page number, and array length as the total page count.

However in this day and age, using JS to display a record at a time makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is ok, but I'd recommend using existing libaries that do the trick of paginating and even constructing HTML for displaying page number buttons, next-previous links and what not.

Please revise http://paginationcfc.riaforge.org/ - a ColdFusion project that deals with pagination quite well and is very easy to implement, saving you tons of work. You could even set it do display one record per page, and the rest (next-previous buttons and maybe "page numbers") would be automagically done by the pagination component.

Ah, doing so (one big query and subsequent sub-queries) I strongly suggest caching.
HTH.

Comment: do you have any other simplest example on this? I'm a bit slow catching up with CF. but i have looked at those example & it seems interesting for me to study.

Comment: There are many examples here: http://www.dopefly.com/projects/pagination/examples/
And here http://www.dopefly.com/projects/pagination/pagination_cfc_documentation.cfm you can find a complete documentation. Unfortunately there is not enough space in SO comments to post code blocks. I'm sure the pagination.cfc's documentation is complete enough to get you started.

Comment: thanks. i have configured the easiest way for me. just one more question. do you mind to see my problem? have updated the question.